# Android `initialize()` is not recognized

Tags: android

So I was following [this tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/camera-hardware/android-camera-example/#code) and got everything mostly working.  But for some reason, the line that says `initialize()` is not being recognized by Android Studio.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.part_camera_view);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    myContext = this;
    initialize(); //This line is not recognized
}
```

I'm way too new to understanding what's going on, so I'm hoping to be nudged in the right direction.  I can't find anything in Android documents that talk about `initialize()`

I've basically copy and pasted the script from the tutorial and changed the specific elements to fit my project.  I am able to see a screen with the buttons provided, but I can not see the live view from the camera, and I believe that line is the problem

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a method called `initialize()` defined in your code?

Comment: I don't and I don't see where it would be in the tutorial (unless I missed it)

Comment: Post your method initialize()

Comment: Then it would appear as though your tutorial is either incomplete or one of their other code snippets is supposed to be the `initialize()` method. Either way, it is certainly not a method in the framework.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize is a function.  It isn't a prebuilt SDK function-  if you want one, you have to write it yourself.  If you don't need one, the call to it shouldn't be there.

As an aside, I have serious concerns about this code without even looking at the link to the tutorial-  there's no reason to store this in a separate variable, and it makes me doubt the author understands his own code.

Comment: Thank you Gabe, that makes sense.  I'm only just starting to look into the camera possibilities and even bad tutorials help you learn!  I will certainly look into the camera via the android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down to the bottom of the tutorials page you will find a link where you can download the source code of the example project. You will find the initialize method in the`AndroidCameraExample` class.